# How to correctly write an MDX expression for a set

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

I've got 2 dimension hierarchies:

- 1 `[Hierarchy1].[CityOfBirth]`
- 2 `[Hierarchy2].[CityOfResidence]`

Both these hierarchies contain same members - cities

How do I write an MDX expression for a set containing all possible combinations of both dimensions

`([Hierarchy1].[CityOfBirth].Member, [Hierarchy2].[CityOfResidence].Member)`

but excluding those tuples where

`[Hierarchy1].[CityOfBirth].Member = [Hierarchy2].[CityOfResidence].Member`

I.e. there shouldn't be tuples like (New York, New York) or (Chicago, Chicago) in the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Filter`, and filter on the `Name` property of the members:

```
Filter(([Hierarchy1].[CityOfBirth].Members * [Hierarchy2].[CityOfResidence].Members)
       as c,
       c.Current.Item(0).Name <> c.Current.Item(1).Name
       )
```

Just be aware that this may need some time to run, as filter iterates across the complete cross product.